# Python: String + String

Tags: python, string-concatenation

On normal cases string + string works but here I cant get URL1 inside my chrome code.

```
URL1 = "https://www.google.com/"
os.system('start chrome "url here" --incognito --window-position=-10,-3 --window-size=550,1030')
```

I've tried doing

```
os.system('start chrome "%s" --incognito --window-position=-10,-3 --window-size=550,1030') % (URL1)
```

but it didn't work either.

Any help?

Comment: os.system(f'start chrome "{URL1}" --incognito --window-position=-10,-3 --window-size=550,1030')

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What happened when "it didn't work either" ? Did you get an error message? Did nothing happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)

Code [try it here](https://repl.it/@NamG1/python-string-string)

```
import os

URL1 = "https://www.google.com/"

os.system(f'start chrome "{URL1}" --incognito --window-position=-10,-3 --window-size=550,1030')
```

Answer (score 3):

You run os.system and then use tuple with URL1, concat with result

```py
os.system('start chrome "%s" --incognito --window-position=-10,-3 --window-size=550,1030') % (URL1)
```

Need change to

```py
os.system(('start chrome "%s" --incognito --window-position=-10,-3 --window-size=550,1030') % (URL1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just try f-string formatting:

```
os.system(f'start chrome {URL1} --incognito --window-position=-10,-3 --window-size=550,1030')
```

This will work.